# O que aconteceu com o stackoverflow?

Tags: debate

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porque o stackOverflow está assim?

Comment: 1 de Abril. Se quiser voltar ao normal aperta o botão "Go to the future".

Comment: Primeiro de abril, também me assustei kaoksaokaso

Comment: **- "Elaaah Foi Hackiaadaahhh Pelos Hackeer Anonimouusss O.O xD xD**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É uma brincadeira que a plataforma fez para o primeiro de abril, caso você queira voltar ao design normal é só apertar o botão "Go to the future"

Comment: Uffaaa! Pensei que fosse vírus na minha máquina .